# MongoDB Authentication failure from mongo java client

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to connect to mongo db version 3.2 using mongo java client version 3.2 and getting the following exception, any idea what went wrong here?

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating
at com.mongodb.connection.NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(NativeAuthenticator.java:48)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'auth failed' on server 10.100.5.41:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "auth failed", "code" : 18 }
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
at com.mongodb.connection.NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(NativeAuthenticator.java:46)
... 5 more
```

Following is the code I used to connect.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = null;

    try {
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("admin", "mydatabase", "admin123".toCharArray());
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("10.100.5.41", 27017), Arrays.asList(credential));

        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydatabase");
        System.out.println(database.getName());
        MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("user");

        MongoCursor cursor = collection.find().iterator();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the user on "mydatabase" or on "admin" (which is the default)? Or in other words, try "admin" as the database in createMongoCRCredential.

Comment: @Zeus the code seems correct. I'm doing the same and have no problem connecting to my servers. Check the logs on your server for errors during the authentication. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-users-collection/

Comment: Please can someone close the question, after hours of debugging, db administrator told that, he has changed the username and password. At times I wonder why I become a Software Engineer.

Comment: @Zeus answer your question with what you just said and accept it

Comment: @neomega great, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13):

After hours of debugging, db administrator told that, he has changed the username and password. At times I wonder why I become a Software Engineer.